# how to change the output data dataformat

Tags: php, html

I want to make a table to show dtatabase data. And I have successful to connect, and let customer to enter the value.

but when i want it to show in table, it is a type of group value show in a lattice like

e.g

```
id : 1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 5

----
|id|
----
|5  | 
|4  |
|3  |
|2  |
|1  |
---
```

i want it to show like this

---

```
|id|
---
|5|
--
|4|
--
|3|
--
|2|
--
|1|
```

let every data show in the table's samll lattice

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G98u5.png)

but the real once show like that

one type data all show in a big lattice , isn't clean enough

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNK7j.png)

How can i improve that?

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>狀態</th> 
    <th>添加時間</th>
    <th>HKPID</th>
    <th>商戶</th>
    <th>客戶代表</th>
    <th>經手人</th>
    <th>客戶聯絡入口</th>
    <th>下次跟進日期</th>
    <th>查看</th>
    <th>修改</th>
    <th>內容</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>  
<?php

$sql = "SELECT  ID FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
      <td>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> " . $row["ID"]. "  <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
       
</td>
           
<?php

$sql = "SELECT  狀態 FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<td>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> " . $row["狀態"]. "  <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
       
</td>
<?php

$sql = "SELECT   添加時間   FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<td>
<?php
        
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> " . $row["添加時間"]. "  <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
       
</td>
<?php

$sql = "SELECT   HKPID FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<td>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> " . $row["HKPID"]. "  <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
</td>
<?php

$sql = "SELECT  商戶  FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<td>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> " . $row["商戶"]. "  <br>";
    }
} else {
  e cho "0 results";
}
?>
       
</td>
<?php

$sql = "SELECT   客戶代表 FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
        ?>
      <td><?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> " . $row["客戶代表"]. "  <br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
        ?>
       
      </td>
      <?php

$sql = "SELECT   經手人  FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
        ?>
      <td><?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> " . $row["經手人"]. "  <br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
        ?>
       
      </td>
      <?php

$sql = "SELECT   客戶聯絡入口  FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
        ?>
      <td><?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> " . $row["客戶聯絡入口"]. "  <br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
        ?>
       
      </td>
        
      <?php

$sql = "SELECT  下次跟進日期 FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
        
        ?>
      <td><?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> " . $row["下次跟進日期"]. "  <br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
        ?>
       
      </td>
      
      <?php

$sql = "SELECT   查看  FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
        ?>
      <br/><td><b><p onclick="layer.open({
  type: 2, 
  content: 'view.php' 
}); " style="color:blue;"><?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> " . $row["查看"]. "  <br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
        ?>      
      </p></b>
       
           
      </td>  
      
       <?php

$sql = "SELECT  修改  FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
        ?>
      <br/><td><?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> " . $row["修改"]. "  <br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
        ?>      
      
     </td>  
      
      
      <?php

$sql = "SELECT   內容 FROM mytable ORDER BY ID desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
        ?>
      <br/><td><center><p onclick=><?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> " . $row["內容"]. "  <br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
        ?>      

           </center>
      </td>  
     

  </tr>
           
           </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You do know that you can select more than one column at a time in q SELECT Query dont you? Like `SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g....`

Comment: i know that but i am't good at that . i don't know the detail of that . How can i use  array of database  to show ?